# Restrict Users To Swap Contact Details

Tags: php

I have a system in which two users can send string message to each other .I just want to trace message if users enter any contact details like email,address[UK],phone number ,mobile number. System is in PHP script I don't want it in JavaScript or else.

Comment: What have you tried? If you don't know where to start, have a look at [the regular expressions](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Regular_expression).

Comment: The hardest part by far is going to be coming up with what to search for in the first place.

Answer (score -1):

You can use a regular expression to match specific format data.
Function you should use: http://php.net/manual/en/function.preg-match.php